# How to extract variable name and value from string and assign to variable in python

Tags: python

I have the following string which i would like to extract the variables and their values

```
text = "family:'DefaultCroSec' name:'' I-Profile:  height:60[cm] Upper-width:35[cm] Lower-width:190[cm] Upper-thick:2[cm] Lower-thick:1.4[cm] Fillet-radius:0[cm] Web-thick:1[cm] zs:15.28[cm] material:'S355' applies to elements:'girders'"
```

i.e

```
height = 60
Upper-width = 35
```

etc etc

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Since this string does not look like any valid python dictionary or JSON code, maybe use splitting to get the names and the values of the "variables" and store them in a dictionary.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any consistent pattern. Sometimes the value is surrounded by quotes, sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex.

```
import re
text = "family:'DefaultCroSec' name:'' I-Profile:  height:60[cm] Upper-width:35[cm] Lower-width:190[cm] Upper-thick:2[cm] Lower-thick:1.4[cm] Fillet-radius:0[cm] Web-thick:1[cm] zs:15.28[cm] material:'S355' applies to elements:'girders'"

print(dict(re.findall(r"([\w\-]+):(\d+\.?\d*)", text)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Fillet-radius': '0',
 'Lower-thick': '1.4',
 'Lower-width': '190',
 'Upper-thick': '2',
 'Upper-width': '35',
 'Web-thick': '1',
 'height': '60',
 'zs': '15.28'}
```